# How to checkout the wordpress.org plugin repository?

Tags: plugins, wordpress.org, repository

I have problems to checkout the wordpress.org plugin repository via SVN on `https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/`.

First it starts all looking well:

```
>svn --force checkout https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/
A    plugins.svn.wordpress.org\lumberjack
...
```

But while it progresses, it gets stuck:

```
...
A    plugins.svn.wordpress.org\gbs-ad-shopping\readme.txt
A    plugins.svn.wordpress.org\gbs-ad-shopping\SaveButton.png
svn: In directory 'plugins.svn.wordpress.org\gbs-ad-shopping'
svn: Can't open file 'plugins.svn.wordpress.org\gbs-ad-shopping\.svn\tmp\text-base\readme.txt.svn-base': Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
```

(*Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.* is German for a file not found error)

So now the working copy is broken. First thing to do I thought is to run a cleanup, but see what happens:

```
>svn cleanup plugins.svn.wordpress.org
svn: In directory 'plugins.svn.wordpress.org\gbs-ad-shopping'
svn: Error processing command 'modify-wcprop' in 'plugins.svn.wordpress.org\gbs-ad-    shopping'
svn: 'plugins.svn.wordpress.org\gbs-ad-shopping\format' is not under version control
```

It looks a bit to me that this plugin is has some weird settings that prevent to checkout it. So any hints on this? Better ask that question over at SE?

Comment: Wait, am I missing something, or are you actually trying to checkout the entire plugins repo? If you look at what gbs-ad-shopping's SVN directory looks like you'll probably cringe.

Comment: I want to run a test on Ticket #13699 and need some meat to throw on the grill. I need fuzz data, so yeah, picking it up.

Comment: I also have a complete SVN plugin "mirror" on my nas. But also for me with tortoise I never managed to get a complete copy at once, somewhere at some stage it just gives an error, so the rest is manual.

Comment: @edelwater: how long did it took for you to do the "mirror"?

Comment: LONG ... VERY LONG... even entering the directory takes a LOT of time while the NAS goes TRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, looks like this is a problem with windows. I tested this now under linux and it worked like a charm. I have no idea what is causing this, but that specific plugin which is problematic is looking wired in svn anyway.

So solution is to use a SVN client on linux. It just works.

Comment: I see there is a `readme.txt` and a `README.txt` in [that plugin's repository](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/gbs-ad-shopping/). It seems [NTFS makes no distinction of filenames based on case](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100108), so SVN gets in trouble because it wants to add a file it already has.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. That makes sense as windows does not differ with case in filenames.

Comment: Should we ask `plugins@wordpress.org` to remove one of the two? This probably bothers others too.

Comment: @Jan - Nah, it's just that you need to checkout via linux. That's all.